# Prove that if $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}\text{ and } abc=8\text{ then } {ab+4\over a+2}+{bc+4\over b+2}+{ca+4\over c+2}\ge6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Question:**

> Prove that if $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}\text{ and } abc=8\text{ then } {ab+4\over a+2}+{bc+4\over b+2}+{ca+4\over c+2}\ge6$

**My Approach:**

Now we have:
$${ab+4\over a+2}={2\times (ab+4)\over2\times (a+2)}={2ab+8\over2(a+2)}={2ab+abc\over2(a+2)}={ab(2+c)\over2(a+2)}$$
Now similarly we can acheive:
$${bc+4\over b+2}={bc(2+a)\over2(b+2)};{ca+4\over c+2}={ca(2+b)\over2(c+2)}$$
Using AM-GM we get:
$${ab+4\over a+2}+{bc+4\over b+2}+{ca+4\over c+2}$$
$$={ab(2+c)\over2(a+2)}+{bc(2+a)\over2(b+2)}+{ca(2+b)\over2(c+2)}$$
$$\ge\sqrt[3]{{ab(2+c)\over2(a+2)}\times{bc(2+a)\over2(b+2)}\times{ca(2+b)\over2(c+2)}}$$
$$=\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2\over2^3}$$
$$=\sqrt[3]{8^2\over8}=2$$
Therefore, we get:
$${ab+4\over a+2}+{bc+4\over b+2}+{ca+4\over c+2}\ge2$$
However, the question wants me to prove that its greater than or equal to $6$ and when I try to plug in I always get a value larger than or equal to $6$. So where did I go wrong and how can I fix my mistake. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to divide the left part by 3, hence you got it, well done

Comment: $(X+Y+Z)/3\geq...$

Comment: @MarcoBellocchi Oh thank you, I guess that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote $$\tfrac{ab(2+c)}{2(a+2)}+\tfrac{bc(2+a)}{b+2)}+\tfrac{ca(2+b)}{2(c+2)}
\ge\sqrt[3]{{ab(2+c)\over2(a+2)}\cdot{bc(2+a)\over2(b+2)}\cdot{ca(2+b)\over2(c+2)}},$$ but it should be
$$\tfrac{ab(2+c)}{2(a+2)}+\tfrac{bc(2+a)}{b+2)}+\tfrac{ca(2+b)}{2(c+2)}
\ge3\sqrt[3]{{ab(2+c)\over2(a+2)}\cdot{bc(2+a)\over2(b+2)}\cdot{ca(2+b)\over2(c+2)}}.$$